# "database disk image is malformed"

Tags: fedora, yum

Running `yum search something` I get:

```
Error: database disk image is malformed
```

How to fix?

Comment: Did you have any prior problems with the database? Did you recently upgrade rpm or yum? Is your RAM or hard disk failing (disk: check the kernel logs; RAM: you'll generally experience other data corruption and crashes)? Did your machine or the utility recently crash in the middle of an rpm or yum operation? Is the disk full or has it been full recently?

Comment: @Gilles Probably because I kept on killing yum when it was doing it's package metadata downloads. Also, I'm running this on a VM, so maybe yum got confused with the messed-up dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try:

```
su -c'yum clean all'
```

and enter your root pw.

Comment: Als, you can use `yum clean dbcache`.